# How to create a random string with 2 specific strings as input in java?

Tags: java

I have a function which takes 2 strings, say userName and password as parameters. I need to generate a random user id with these 2 strings as input. Can anyone suggest a solution ?

`generateUserId(String userName, String password)`

Thanks

Comment: do you mean a cryptographic strong hash or is it just some randomized text?

Comment: yes it depends on the purpose of the `id`

Comment: The name of your function might reveal a problem: if you intend to identify users by this string, you might have a problem when a user wants to change his password... Either it is badly named or you have a serious design problem.

Comment: I am new to Java. What i got while searching is the usage of **Math.random()** . But this doesnot have any dependency with the input strings.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish with the user id? wouldn't it make more sense to use an autoincrement with the column of the id?

Comment: @SamuelRossille This is just for a prototype model. Thanks for pointing out the issue.

Comment: @DhruvGairola This id can repeat in dB. This is not the unique identifier for the row

Answer (score 2):

This might help: `http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html`
Fiddle around with it.

```
String res = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes((password+username).getBytes()).toString();
System.out.println(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

how about something like this

```
int seed = userName.hashCode() & password.hashCode(); 
return new String(new Random(seed).nextLong());
```